# Navigating between activities back and forth

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, workflow

## Situation

There are 3 activities in my app:

1. Activity A - showing list of incoming messages and two actions:

   - compose new message
   - reply to existing message
2. Activity B - showing list of possible recipients of new message
3. Activity C - enabling UI for composing new message with selected recipient

### Workflow for the *new message* action

1. A starts B
2. In B user selects recipient
3. B starts C with recipient identification provided as intent extra
4. In C new message is composed
5. C starts A
6. A informs user that message has been sent

Workflow for the *reply* action

1. A starts directly C with recipient identification provided  as intent extra
2. *No such step*
3. *No such step*
4. In C new message is composed
5. C starts A
6. A informs user that message has been sent

As you can see, the workflows are very similar.

## What I don't like about this?

1. The re-creating of the activity A in step 5.
2. Having to differentiate between going into A for the first time and returning from C when deciding if to show "Message was sent" toast or not

## My ideas of how to solve this

### Option 1 - activities and `startActivityForResult`

- I'd like to use `startActivityForResult` to start the activity C
- However, activity B seems to be standing in the way sometimes - see workflow for new message
- Don't know how to handle this activity *in-between* problem

### Option 2 - Fragments and `startActivityForResult`

- What about merging B and C into one activity, let's call it D,
- In D to have two fragments, let's call them FB and FB, with same functionality as have the respective activities B and C
- Then I would start D from A every time via the `startActivityForResult`
- Based on the intent extra provided to D could decide if to show fragment FB or display fragment FC

## What approach should I choose? Please suggest.